# Editing file metadata with a Powershell function (called from MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, powershell, attributes, metadata

I'm trying to programatically access local file metadata (similar to fields like "Authors" or "Album" in a .mp3 file) using Powershell (main reason being that this seemed to me to be the most viable way to achieve this from MATLAB).

So far I have managed to **read** the metadata. I've come up with following function:

```
param(        
    [string]$folderName = "C:\temp\Powershell\test",
    [string]$fileName = "test.txt",
    [string]$attrNameToSearch = "Size"
    )


$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace($folderName) 

$iAttr = 0     
while($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $iAttr) -ne $attrNameToSearch) {
    $iAttr += 1    
}

$file = $objFolder.ParseName($fileName)

$attrValue = $objFolder.getDetailsOf($file, $iAttr)             

return $attrValue
```

It seems to work perfectly from the ISE as well as when I call it from MATLAB with:

```
cmd = sprintf(['powershell -file psFunction4.ps1 -folderName c:\\temp\\Powershell\\test -fileName ', fileNames{iF}, ' -attrName Size']);
[~, b] = system(cmd)
```

Now the question is: is there any way to use a similar approach to **edit** the metada?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-6) may do what you want. But it depends what types of file metadata you want to edit. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dominic. What I specifically want is to access (read and edit) one particular field ("Comments") of .mdf files, which is the format in which our data acquisition system saves the measurement data. I guess a more common example would be to edit something like "Authors" or "Album" of a mp3 file.